# Passing DateTime as a parameter between android client and WCF Service using Json

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, rest

I'm trying to get a list of objects filtering by DateTime (Joda DateTime) with android as client, from a WCF Service. I'm using Json and REST to do the request.

How can I pass the datetime value as a parameter?

Something like:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost( SERVICE_URI + "/GetScheduleEntrysByDate/" + date.toString());
```

And this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "GetScheduleEntrysByDate/{date}",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<ScheduleEntry> GetScheduleEntrysByDate(DateTime date);
```

Comment: In your url, add the following "?datetime=datetimeValueYouWantToSend".  Please check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: It does not work. Why check out FAQ?

Comment: ahh you edited the question and added code,  NICE!

Answer (score 0):

```
// you might wanna specify custom params here for the DefaultHttpClient contructor
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost( SERVICE_URI + "/GetScheduleEntrysByDate/" + date.toString());

List<NameValuePair> bodyParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
bodyParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", new Date().getTime());
if (bodyParams.size() > 0) {
    try {
        // Include the request body
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(bodyParams));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Body parameters produced unsupported encoding?", e);
    }
}
// sends the POST with params,  you will need to put this in a try catch
try {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
} catch (Exception e){
}
```